# what are the factors of authentications that can be used as second factor in ping identity?

Tags: pingfederate, two-factor-authentication

I tried out with the ping identity documentation for the last days.

What are the factors of authentications that can be used as second factor in ping identity?

From where I will get a good example for two factor authentication using `pingFederate`?

Answer (score 0):

Within the PingFederate Administration console you will need to configure IdP Adapters along with a composite adapter.  A specific example would be to have the out-of-the-box HTML Form IdP Adapter and the PingID Adapter configured into a composite adapter.  The composite adapter is essentially an authentication chain that utilizes individual IdP Adapters.  In the example above, HTML Form Authentication would be the first factor that displays a username/password interface to the user.  Assuming that is successful, the second factor in the chain would be PingID, which is a mobile phone app that the user would need to swipe to prove they have the phone associated to their username.

PingID is an integration kit that is available on the Ping Identity Download page https://www.pingidentity.com/en/products/downloads.html.  If you download the PingID Integration Kit, the User Guide will show you how to configure two factor authentication.

Additional integration kits are available for Ping Federate that are listed on the downloads page as well. In addition to these download components, there are third party IdP Adapters available such as ThreatMetrix and RSA Adaptive Authentication for context-based authentication. From the perspective of the Admin Console, an IdP Adapter is an Authentication capability. Thus, multi-factor authentication is achieved through the composite adapter that chains together the IdP Adapters.